# Does an analog of the NHibernate.ToFuture() extension method exist in the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate

So the question is in the header.

What NHibernate users can do:

```
var q1 = Source.Companies.ToFuture();
var q2 = Source.Items.ToFuture();
var q3 = Source.Users.ToFuture();

var compoundModel = new CompoundModel(q1, q2, q3); 
// All data obtained in single database roundtrip 
// When the first to future statement is touched
```

How to mimic such behavior in EF 4?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because EF doesn't have a feature like NHibernate's MultiQuery. The closest I can think of is a `union` but of course that can never cover your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no because EF is not able to work with multiple result sets.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension to Entity Framework called [`Future Queries`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) that allows queries to be queued and processed at the same time.

I have never used `CompoundModel` so you have to check it.