# EF 6 equivalent of NHibernate ToFuture

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nhibernate

My experience with ORMs is limited to NHibernate at the moment.

However, I have just started working on a new project that is using EF6.

In Linq to NHibernate we have the ability to defer query execution and hydration multiple queries in a single round trip like this:

```
// apples will be an IEnumerable<Apple> and won't be hydrated until it is enumerated 
// or another query is hydrated
var apples = session.Query<Apple>().Where(a => a.Type = "red").ToFuture();

// oranges will be an IEnumerable<Orange> and won't be hydrated until it is enumerated 
// or another query is hydrated
var oranges = session.Query<Orange>().Where(a => a.Type = "small").ToFuture();

// this will hydrate all three queries
var grapes = session.Query<Grape>().Where(a => a.Type = "red").ToFuture().ToList();
```

Someone has posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297900/does-an-analog-of-the-nhibernate-tofuture-extension-method-exist-in-the-entity) but regarding EF4. I was wondering if the `ToFuture` feature has been introduced in EF6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate equivalent of Entity Framework "Future Queries"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061552/nhibernate-equivalent-of-entity-framework-future-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToFuture` is not in the EF6 as a core feature.

However, an open source project called [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) provides some additional functionality to EF, *Futures* included.

The EF extended syntax is `Future`.

The [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/) appears to support EF 6.

Comment: I'll try it out. Thanks again

Comment: No problem buddy. Glad I could help